# Applying Chandan on God statues

Tags: scripture, belief

Some elders say that chandan should not be applied on God statues. If the statue is in stone form chandan is applied on the forehead,at the two end of the eyes, ears nowadays. Any scriptural evidence that chandan should not be applied in these cases?